# Is it possible to edit IOS UI in text mode/non-gui

Tags: ios, xcode

I am just starting out learning iOS development as a hobby in my spare time - so please be patient if this question seems dumb.

But how do I edit the UI without using the xcode graphical user interface? Is there some like underlying XML definition like Android has in android studio?

The reason I ask is if I ever need to change 1 dimension, it means I would have to manually go to every single storyboard element, and change it by hand as opposed to editing them efficiently from some main config file like `dimens.xml`

Comment: My first reaction is that if you need to make that sort of change then you haven't adopted autolayout correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select your storyboard in Xcode, right click, and choose Open As -> Source Code, you will see the XML.

It's not simple to work with in that form (in my opinion), but it's available.